# Get two rows to display in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate two values: Cost of Delay and WSJF, using SQL.

The calculated sum of Cost of Delay is used to calculate WSJF.

When I do the calculation for WSJF, I only get the new row and value for WSJF to display in a table, Cost of Delay is removed.

| Variable | Score Value |
| --- | --- |
| Revenue | 8 |
| Cost Savings | 1 |
| Development Effort | 13 |
| Strategic Value | 20 |
| Legal Risk | 5 |
| Time Criticality | 5 |

To calculate Cost of Delay I used the following function

```
SELECT SUM ('Score Value') As 'Cost of Delay'
FROM T1
WHERE Variable IN ("Revenue", "Cost Savings", "Strategic Value", "Time Criticality");
```

On it's own it prints out as expected

| Cost of Delay | 34 |
| --- | --- |

To calculate the other value I need, WSJF, I used the following

```
`SELECT 100* 
(
    (
SELECT SUM ('Score Value') As 'Cost of Delay'
FROM T*
WHERE Variable IN ("Revenue", "Cost Savings", "Strategic Value", "Time Criticality")
) / (
SELECT SUM ('Score Value') As 'Other'
FROM T1
WHERE Variable IN ("Legal Risk", "Development Effort")
  ) 
 )
 AS WSJF;`
```

Which correctly gives me

| WSJF | 189 |
| --- | --- |

Ideally I'd like a table be displayed with the combination of these two

| VALUE | SCORE |
| --- | --- |
| Cost of Delay | 34 |
| WSJF | 189 |

I am at a loss for how to connect these two functions into one. I have tried adding an additional SELECT statement at the top but receive errors.

Comment: You can use a *case expression*. note your usage of single/double quotes is reversed.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Not really without knowing your specific RDBMS which you have not tagged.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator, which "combines the result-set of two or more SELECT statements".

For your particular question, I believe this would satisfy your requirements:

```
SELECT SUM ('Score Value') As 'Cost of Delay'
FROM T1
WHERE Variable IN ("Revenue", "Cost Savings", "Strategic Value", "Time Criticality")
UNION
SELECT 100* 
(
    (
SELECT SUM ('Score Value') As 'Cost of Delay'
FROM T*
WHERE Variable IN ("Revenue", "Cost Savings", "Strategic Value", "Time Criticality")
) / (
SELECT SUM ('Score Value') As 'Other'
FROM T1
WHERE Variable IN ("Legal Risk", "Development Effort")
  ) 
 )
 AS WSJF;
```

However, to achieve the column names being `value` and `score`, I would create a table (optionally you can make this a [temporary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) table):

```
CREATE TABLE yourtablenamehere (value text, score int)
```

then I would execute an `INSERT INTO yourtablenamehere (value, score) VALUES`  followed by the select statement I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sum window function with a case expression as the following:

```
with cte as 
(
  select 
    case 
       when Variable in ('Revenue', 'Cost Savings', 'Strategic Value', 'Time Criticality') then 'Cost of Delay'
       when Variable in ('Legal Risk', 'Development Effort') then 'WSJF'
    end as value_type, 
    sum(case when Variable in ('Revenue', 'Cost Savings', 'Strategic Value', 'Time Criticality') then Score_Value end) over () as sum1,
    sum(case when Variable in ('Legal Risk', 'Development Effort') then Score_Value end) over () as sum2
  from T1
)
select value_type,
  case 
   when value_type = 'Cost of Delay' then max(sum1)
   when value_type = 'WSJF' then 100.0 * max(sum1) / max(sum2) -- or maybe round(100.0 * max(sum1) / max(sum2), 0)
  end as score
from cte
group by value_type -- the aggregation is used to eliminate the duplicates
order by value_type
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fN9M8hfv)